# Report sometimes not writing to file

Tags: c#, file, text

I have a program where I can add a list of car boot sales to the program as well as specify if they are for charity etc. There is also a button to generate a list of car boot sales which are for charities and those that are not to different text files. When I add the the charity boot sales to the application and generate the list, it writes to the file fine. However, when I load up the application again and try to generate the file, it generates a blank list. (I have the function of saving the application data on exit and reloading the data on starting up).

I'm not sure why this could be happening??

Here is the code behind the button for generating the list to the file:

```
        List<CarBootSale> carbootsales = carBootSaleList.ReturnList();
        carbootsales.Sort(delegate(CarBootSale bs1, CarBootSale bs2)
        {
            return Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(bs1.ID, bs2.ID);
        });
        textReportGenerator.GenerateCharityReport(carbootsales, AppData.CHARITY);
        MessageBox.Show("All the Charity Car Boot Sales have been written to the report file: " + AppData.CHARITY);
```

Here is the code in the TextReportGenerator class which generates the report:

```
        FileStream outFile;
        StreamWriter writer;

        //create the file and write to it
        outFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);

        //For each object in the list, add it to the file
        foreach (CarBootSale obj in CharityList)
        {
            if (obj.Charity == "true")
            {
                writer.WriteLine(obj.Display());
            }
        }
        //close the file which has been opened
        writer.Close();
        outFile.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code largely looks fine (note: see below), so without having the entire code to run locally I can't give specific advice, except to use `using`.

Consider using code like this:

```
    using(FileStream outFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile)) {

        //For each object in the list, add it to the file
        foreach (CarBootSale obj in CharityList) {
            if (obj.Charity == "true") {
                writer.WriteLine(obj.Display());
            }
        }

    }
```

My guess is that there's an exception in your `Display` method that isn't being handled, so your calls to `.Close` will never be made, so the data is never flushed from the buffer and out to disk. Using a `using` block guarantees that the regardless of what happens (an exception or premature `return`) your stream's buffer will be written to disk without any loss of data.

One small thing: why is `.Charity` a string? Why isn't it a `boolean` or `enum` property?

Comment: Your code worked great, thanks a lot for your help! :) I did try boolean earlier but it threw up a lot of errors so I changed it back to string.